# How to mock the return type Try<Unit> in a Spring Boot reactive unit test with Kotlin?

Tags: spring, kotlin, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for a function in my Spring Boot reactive application that returns a Try object. Here's an example of the function signature:

```java
suspend fun upsertUser(uuid: UUID, creditorIds: Collection<String>, xid: String?): Try<Unit> = 
    runCatching {
        // Implementation code here
    }
```

I'm using coEvery from the MockK library to mock the function call in my unit test, but I'm not sure how to specify the return value for a Try object. Here's an example of my current mock setup:

```java
// userService is a mock object of the class that contains upsertUser
coEvery { userService.upsertUser(any(), any(), any()) } returns ...
```

What should I put in place of the ... to return a Try object with a successful result?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Is this `kotlin.runCatching`? Doesn't that return a [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/), not a `Try`?